# CakePHP, selecting MySQL records by one or more Ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I want to select MySQL records based on a list of Ids thats called from:

```
$ids = $this->params['url']['ids']
```

Where ids is one or more Ids, seperated by comma.  I know I could use explode to get the Ids in an array:

```
$id = explode(",", $ids);
```

I know to the basic code of calling by Id is:

```
$row = $this->Model->find('all',
       array(
              'conditions' => array(
                   'id' => $id['0'],
              ),
              'fields' => array(
                   'id',
                   'name'
              )
       ));
```

My question is how can I select using multiple Ids without knowing the AMOUNT of ids I have before hand?  I.e. 1 Id, or 3 ids, or 5 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should work with `'id' => $id`.  That is, pass in an array of IDs to search to use an `IN` clause.

Comment: See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: well cool.  didn't think it would just do it automatically.  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

pass $id as an array, CakePHP auto detect if array is given in conditions, it auto change "=" into "IN" mysql.

```
$row = $this->Model->find('all',
       array(
              'conditions' => array(
                   'id' => $id,
              ),
              'fields' => array(
                   'id',
                   'name'
              )
       ));
```